# How to add path for adding (p12) Certificate with amplify add notification command on mac os terminal?

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I wanna add my certificate path to my terminal from my download folder.

I tried /downloads/certificate.p12
but it getting file path must be valid.

```
Choose authentication method used for APNs Certificate
The certificate file path (.p12):  /downloads/certificate.p12
file path must be valid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move certificate file in the directory in which you are using amplify add notification command and try to just call name of file (*.p12) it will work